# Database problems when starting the Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

Updated the spring version from 1.5.6 to 2.7.9, changed the driver from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver (database version 10.5.16-MariaDB)
After that, an error began to appear:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Hashtable.java:1387)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.mapPropertiesToOption(Configuration.java:611)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.parseInternal(Configuration.java:589)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:518)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:96)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.iba.asokp.analitycs.Application.main(Application.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

Current application.properties (changed some confidential configs)

```
# connection
spring.notification.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.notification.jdbc-url=jdbc:mariadb://${DB_CONNECTION_URL}:${DB_CONNECTION_PORT}/ibacontrol?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.notification.username=${DB_CONNECTION_USERNAME}
spring.notification.password=${DB_CONNECTION_PASSWORD}
spring.notification.name=ibacontrol
spring.notification.maxActive=5
spring.notification.test-while-idle=true
spring.notification.validation-query=SELECT 1
spring.notification.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=100000
spring.notification.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=10000
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false
isnotify.enable=true
url=jdbc:mariadb://${DB_CONNECTION_URL}:${DB_CONNECTION_PORT}/ibacontrol
notificator.threadPool=100
reactor.threadPool=100
enabled=true
server=server
from=from
login=login
pass=pass
```

There are many places where they write that the problem occurs due to сollection changing while some thread is traversing over it ([Java Concurrent Modification Exception (enumerator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138582/java-concurrent-modification-exception-enumerator), for example). But I don't do it in code

Comment: That was addressed in [version 3.1.2 of mariadb-connector-j](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-j/releases)

Answer (score 1):

As [Andrey B. Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov) mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75704605/database-problems-when-starting-the-spring-boot-application#comment133553689_75704605), upgrading mariadb-java-client to version 3.1.4 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This saved my day, Thank you. I upgraded Spring Boot to v2.7.13 and got the same error. Resolved after upgrading the mariadb-java-client version.

Comment: Not working for me even after upgrading to 3.1.2 and 3.1.4. i have moved spring from 2.7.0 to 2.7.11 and using jdbcTemplate to initialise the hikari connection

Comment: @NitikaBansal There don't appear to be any issues with using Spring Boot 2.7.11 and MariaDB Java Client 3.1.4 together for me.
Can you provide more context or specific details from the log?